# Convert a cell with 1:04 (mm:ss), to 64 (mm)

Tags: excel

I am trying to take a cell in Excel that includes a summarized value e.g. 00:30 + 00:34 = 1:04, and I would like it to show in another cell as 64 (minutes).

How do I do this? I have been trying to use the `CONVERT` command, but have not yet succeeded.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the format of the cell from `mm:ss` to `[m]:ss` (or just `[m]` if you don't want to display seconds).

This will make minutes overflow over 60, without displaying as hours:mins.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with "convert". But keep in mind that you will need to address each 'element' of your end product separately - that is, the hours & the minutes in your original cell. Assuming your data is in A1 in the Time format, use the following:

```
=CONVERT(HOUR(A1),"hr","mn")+MINUTE(A1)
```

This takes the number of hours present in A1, converts those to minutes, and adds the minutes already present.